# Picasa Web Album for android

Tags: android, image, api, picasa

I am trying to use Picasa Web Album API from android. I am able to get the albums from a user from AlbumEntry object. From this object, i called getID to get the id of the album but it gives me the url instead : https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/user/{userid}/albumid/{album id}, why does it print a url and not the album id. If I pass this to UserFeed and try to retrieve the photos, I have error.

When I used this url : https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/{user id}/albumid/{album id}?kind=photo, I have no error.

Can somebody they me why getID retrieve the url instead of the album id.

Comment: How you can access {userid} ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem today. I found out that to get only AlbumID, you have to to use `getGphotoId()` method of AlbumEntry Object.